# XSLT: Transform XML Using Group, Duplicate Check and Sort

Tags: sorting, group-by, duplicates, xslt-grouping, xslt-3.0

I have the following problem statement now. I will be having the following XML file as below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <EmpD>
          <PR>
            <RType>02</RType>
            <Emp>888</Emp>
          </PR>
          <PR>
            <RType>02</RType>
            <Emp>889</Emp>
          </PR>
          <JR>
            <RType>01</RType>
            <Emp>888</Emp>
            <Type>C</Type>
            <EDate>2020-05-01</EDate>
            <HR>1210148900</HR>
            <JobC>Test</JobC>
          </JR> 
          <JR>
            <RType>01</RType>
            <Emp>888</Emp>
            <Type>NC</Type>
            <EDate>2020-05-01</EDate>
            <HR>1210148900</HR>
            <JobC>Test</JobC>
          </JR> 
          <JR>
            <RType>01</RType>
            <Emp>888</Emp>
            <Type>C</Type>
            <EDate>2020-05-02</EDate>
            <HR>1210148900</HR>
            <JobC>Test</JobC>
          </JR>
          <JR>
            <RType>01</RType>
            <Emp>889</Emp>
            <Type>C</Type>
            <EDate>2020-05-01</EDate>
            <HR>1210148900</HR>
            <JobC>Test</JobC>
          </JR> 
          <JR>
            <RType>01</RType>
            <Emp>889</Emp>
            <Type>NC</Type>
            <EDate>2020-05-01</EDate>
            <HR>1210148900</HR>
            <JobC>Test</JobC>
          </JR> 
          <JR>
            <RType>01</RType>
            <Emp>889</Emp>
            <Type>NC</Type>
            <EDate>2020-05-02</EDate>
            <HR>1210148900</HR>
            <JobC>Test</JobC>
          </JR>  
        </EmpD>
```

1. So, basically the JR node here can be duplicate based on the Emp and EDate. Is there any possibility to check duplicate against the combination of Emp and EDate and then remove those?
2. My final output XML should look like below, meaning it should sorted by Emp(both for PR and JR) and also with the EDate.

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <EmpD>
      <PR>
        <RType>02</RType>
        <Emp>888</Emp>
      </PR>
      <JR>
        <RType>01</RType>
        <Emp>888</Emp>
        <EDate>2020-05-01</EffectiveDate>
        <HR>1210148900</HR>
        <JobC>Test</JobC>
      </JR>
      <JR>
        <RType>01</RType>
        <Emp>888</Emp>
        <EDate>2020-05-02</EffectiveDate>
        <HR>1210148900</HR>
        <JobC>Test</JobC>
      </JR>
      <JR>
        <RType>01</RType>
        <Emp>889</Emp>
        <EDate>2020-05-01</EffectiveDate>
        <HR>1210148900</HR>
        <JobC>Test</JobC>
      </JR> 
      <PR>
        <RType>02</RType>
        <Emp>889</Emp>
      </PR>
      <JR>
        <RType>01</RType>
        <Emp>889</Emp>
        <EDate>2020-05-01</EffectiveDate>
        <HR>1210148900</HR>
        <JobC>Test</JobC>
      </JR>
      <JR>
        <RType>01</RType>
        <Emp>889</Emp>
        <EDate>2020-05-02</EffectiveDate>
        <HR>1210148900</HR>
        <JobC>Test</JobC>
      </JR>  
    <EmpD>
   ```
3. Also, the Type field is important. We only need to consider where the Type value is "C".
4. I need to finally create a CSV type content. Can we generate from here? Or it means, I need to first generate a XML and then convert into CSV?

Comment: This is a [*grouping*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) question (as your title correctly states). Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: @Tim C - need your help pls

Comment: @Martin Honnen - I know you can help me :)

Comment: XSLT 3 has support for more than one grouping key using e.g. `<xsl:for-each-group select="JR" composite="yes" group-by="Emp, EDate"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:for-each-group>`. So that would allow you to eliminate the JR duplicates. Sorting can be done with `perform-sort`. It is not clear at what point you only want to consider the `Type` as `C`, whether for the duplicate elimination, the sorting, the final output. But it looks anyway like a task where you would want to chain several transformation steps or several XSLT stylesheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a composite key in XSLT 3 to eliminate duplicates, either with `for-each-group` or with the `key` function:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    
  <xsl:key name="dups" match="JR" composite="yes" use="Emp, EDate"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="EmpD">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
              <xsl:sort select="Emp"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="JR[not(. is key('dups', (Emp, EDate))[1])]"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxDjimB

Comment: Thanks @Martin. You are great as always!!. Can we also sort within the JR node based on the date along with the Emp? I mean the sort which you define is correct but also I need the JR node to be sorted according to EDate long with the Emp

Comment: @SreejataPal, you can of course add more `xsl:sort` instructions inside of the `xsl:apply-templates`: `<xsl:sort select="Emp"/><xsl:sort select="EDate"/>`, see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxDjimB/1

Comment: Thanks @Martin. What will happen if I have to generate header and trailer node? Suppose my source structure has header node will have some 2/3 fields with some constant values but Trailer node will have 2 fields i.e: count of Jr and pr but these count need to be calculated in the xslt I believe as XSLT is removing some nodes here.

Comment: @SreejataPal, please don't try to ask new questions in comments to answers, raise a new question showing minimal but complete samples of input, wanted output, XSLT you have tried, result you get together with a textual description of the task you want to solve.

Comment: Sorry for that @Martin

Comment: @Martin.I have written the code for the count of JR which should be taken from the output as this JR in the output structure will have remove duplicates node.
        <xsl:value-of select="count(//JR/[not(. is key('dups', (EmployeeID, EffectiveDate))[1])])"/>. This code mostly works but often results zero.